# iOS Facebook SDK sending private message to friends

Tags: facebook, ios7, xmpp

There are many similar questions here on SO but i am asking it because FB changes its guidelines quite often. Also this question is relevant to specific scenario.

I want my iOS app to send some **text and link** as a private message to selected friends.

Now FB has barred this. But can we send it using FB chat API using **Jabber, XMPP**?
Will that be allowed and not considered as spam?

Any input will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So i finally figured it out.

I used FB SDK version 1 and XMPPFramework. 
I managed to send private message to friends.